# Implement Excel Sheet functionality in Java using data structures

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, hashmap

I want to create Excel Sheet functionality in Java, 
I want to perform below operations in Excel in same way like we have in Microsoft Excel or Google Worksheet:
Add a row/column/cell in the excel sheet.
Delete a row/column/cell in the excel sheet.

I want to perform these operations in an efficient way.which data structures is best suited for this use case.

I have tried using doubly linked list and hash map. In order to delete any cell, row or column, using linked list i can do that , and used hash-map so that traversal and search is faster , but i am not able to figure out all the update, add, and delete operations. Any reference or recommendation is of great help.

Note: I do not want to read/write from Excel.
I want to implement Excel functionality itself using data structure and algorithm.

Comment: You could use the Apache POI library.

Comment: @Polywhirl: My intention is not to read/write data from excel.

Comment: "Excel Sheet functionality" is too vague. please be more precise in what you seek to accomplish. "I want to create an spreadsheet-like application in Java" sounds like it suit you more. without narrowing the scope of your question, you will not get any good answers

Comment: So you want to be able to add/delete/move rows AND columns?

Comment: yes, i have updated the details now. @Polywhirl : Yes, exactly, I want to add/delete rows/columns/cells like we have in Microsoft excel.

Comment: Well, not only do you need a data-structure, you will need a UI... Swing, JavaFX, etc. so unless you have a working demo or attempt, this is too broad.

Comment: What Excel functionality do you want to implement? I hope not all of it...

Comment: Currently i am not worrying about UI stuff. My concern is on creating the backend of this , and how i will maintain the data , and in which data structure. Like i am thinking of doubly linked list which will help in deletion or addition of cells/nodes. , At the same time when user delete complete row ,  i do not want to move/update bunch of data.

Comment: @deHaar : Not all, only addition/deletion of cells/rows primarily.

Comment: You need a dependency graph between cells.